# Wrap page number in colored box in footer

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I a looking for a way to achieve the following outcome for the page numnbers in my footer created using fancyhdr:

[image: Desired outcome]

My current code in a stand-alone example looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,parskip=full]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=4.5cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

% Header and footer
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\chead{\small{\leftmark}}
\lfoot{\small{Author name}}
\rfoot{\small{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\section{Section One}

\lipsum

\clearpage

\section{Section Two}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This of course leads to a pretty much standard outcome:

[image: Current outcome]

The closest thing I found in the fancyhdr documenatation are the thumb-indexes however I am not sure how to adapt them for this.

Is there an easy way to do this or would it require a lot of custom drawing with tikz?

I appreciate all hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of you are using the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` I would suggest to use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead `fancyhdr`. Then you can define and insert a new layer for the background of the pagenumber.

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=enddot,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=4.5cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% header and footer
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.3pt,footsepline=.3pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\leftmark}
\ifoot{Author name}

\newcommand\pagenumberwidth{1cm}% <- width of the black box
\ofoot{\makebox[\pagenumberwidth]{\pagemark}}

% new layer for the pagenumber background:
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=scrheadings.foot.oneside,% <- clone the foot layer
    contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\raggedleft\rule{\pagenumberwidth}{\baselineskip}}}%<- black rule
  ]{pagenumber.bg}
% add the new layer to the pagestyle before the foot layer:
\AddLayersToPageStyleBeforeLayer{scrheadings}{pagenumber.bg}{scrheadings.foot.oneside}

% fonts
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small\upshape}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{white}}% <- white pagenumber

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you could add the black box to the layer of the `headsepline` and move this layer to the background:

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=enddot,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=4.5cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%Header and footer
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.3pt,footsepline=.3pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}[2015/02/07]
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead{\leftmark}
\ifoot{Author name}

\newcommand\pagenumberwidth{1cm}% <- width of the black box
\ofoot{\makebox[\pagenumberwidth]{\pagemark}}
\ModifyLayer[
  background,
  addcontents={%
    \nobreak\makebox[0pt][r]{\smash{\raisebox{-\height}{%
      \parbox{\layerwidth}{\raggedleft\rule{\pagenumberwidth}{\baselineskip}}%
  }}}}
]{scrheadings.foot.above.line}

% fonts
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\small\upshape}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\color{white}}% <- white pagenumber

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Note, that the option `addcontents` was implemented in KOMA-Script version 3.16 (2015/02/07). So you need this or a newer version to run the second example.

Comment: In the first version your request a specific version for scrlayer-scrpage. Why?

Comment: Oh, sorry: The first example does not need a specific `scrlayer-scrpage` version. But the second example needs version 3.16 or newer because `addcontents` was implemented in this version.

Answer (score 5):

My first thought would be to use `TikZ`, but you don't need `TikZ` if you're willing to load the `xcolor` package.

Here's my poor man's version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\chead{\small{\leftmark}}
\lfoot{\small{Author name}}
\rfoot{\mypage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\mypage{%%
  \raisebox{2 pt}[0pt][0pt]{%%
  \rule[-1ex]{1cm}{3.5ex}%%
  \hspace*{-0.5cm}%%
  \makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{white}{\small\thepage}}%%
  \hspace*{0.5cm}}%%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-140]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @A. Ellett I'm not a tikz expert can you put the code of how will you do the same thing using tikz Thanks!!!